# How do I safely clone a Linux VM in Hyper-V?

Tags: linux, virtualization, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

This is a home lab, so nothing critical.  I have a base Linux ISO I'm installing for all my VMs, but the install takes a long time, and even once it's done, I still have to go install a ton of updates and a few packages.  I would like to start cloning my VM's off of a base VM which I keep up-to-date.

My first thought was just to copy the VHDX file and spin up a new machine connected to that, but then I had second thoughts, since I realized I might run into conflicts with MAC addresses, IP addresses, machine names, etc (probably more I'm just not thinking of).

What do I need to do to minimize conflicts like this?  Is there anything beyond MAC address, IP address, and host name which I ought to be worried about?  Or can I really  just copy the VHDX and spin up a new machine?  Is there a better way to do this, while minimizing conflicts between the cloned machines?

---

**EDIT:**  Any reason for the downvotes?  I'm happy to revise or relocate my question if it's poorly constructed or belongs somewhere else.

Comment: There are some [blogs](http://www.jasoncoltrin.com/?p=784) about this.

Answer (score 4):

For Windows guests you'd use Sysprep to generalize the VM that you're using as your template. I don't know if something similar exists for Linux.

As for the MAC address, each cloned VM will have it's own unique MAC address, which is generated by Hyper-V so that shouldn't be an issue.

As for the ip address, if you use DHCP to assign ip addresses then this shouldn't be an issue either.

The only real issue I see is with the hostname.

Comment: And Linux does not care about hostname the same way a Windows box will bitch about mutiple machines with the same machinename. Just change/script changing your hosts/hostname file or /etc/sysconfig/network and you should be good as joeqwerty said